# Capistrano 3 + AWS: Deployment Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

The issue I'm running into is this error when I try to push to production:
The deploy has failed with an error:

```
#<Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: ec2-user>
```

I've tried quite a few Stackoverflow solutions, but to no avail. My deploy.rb is

```
set :user, 'ec2-user'
set :application, 'name of application on git'
set :repo_url, 'the url from my remote origin to git'
set :deploy_to, 'where my apache points but minus the /public'
```

my production.rb is

```
role :app, %w{ip}
role :web, %w{ip} (same as above)
role :db,  %w{ip}

set :ssh_options, {
  user: "ec2-user",
  keys: %w(location to .pem file that I use to ssh in on),
  forward_agent: false,
}
```

I have tried creating new keys for both and using those as outlined here http://craiccomputing.blogspot.com/2008/08/ec2-ssh-and-capistrano.html [cap uses admin instead of ec2-user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536803/cap-uses-admin-instead-of-ec2-user)

But still no dice.

Thoughts?

Comment: can you guide me on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097586/capistrano-with-ubuntu-ec2-instance-to-deploy-ruby-on-rails) ?

Comment: Can you create a stackoverflow post? What have you tried, how did it fail? Both this and the other post referenced have clear steps to take to try to solve them; did you take them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the permissions on your `/home/ec2-user/.ssh` directory and `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys file. They should be something like this:

```
ec2-user@ec2-server:~/.ssh$ ls -la
total 24
drwx------ 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Jan 31 00:39 .
drwx------ 5 root root 4096 Jan 31 21:59 ..
-rw------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user  731 Jan 31 20:39 authorized_keys
-r-------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 3243 Jan 31 20:39 id_rsa
-r-------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user  731 Jan 31 20:39 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 1976 Jan 31 20:39 known_hosts
```

You can also try to deploy as a different user.

Comment: This was my problem -- my authorized_keys allowed read/write from the group and other users. Doing a `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` made it start working.

Answer (score 0):

I was being foolish; I provided the .pem for my Rails ec2 but not my DB ec2.